Access internal cloud file to upload
I am using internal cloud where i have few files inside some folder. In the same cloud i have another page where i used one file upload control. When i try to upload file it takes me to the local system to upload the file, But i need here to upload the file which is available in the same cloud. How do i provide command or do some setting to locate the internal cloud when user try to upload any file instead of local system.
What i have tried so far:
Below is the input file upload code.
<input type="file" accept=".zip,.rar,.7zip" />

Kindly suggest.

Hello everyone, Any update on above asked?
